# Delphi DBCombobox in Delphi XE app, only shows values if in .Items and not the actual nonconforming Datafield value

Tags: delphi, ado, master-detail

I've encountered a very strange DBComboBox problem in a master/detail app using Access via ADO. If you have a DBComboBox (.Style=csDropDown) containing a list of items and you enter some text that doesn't exist in the list, the value in the table's DBComboBox field won't appear when navigating back to that record. I've used the DBNavigator.OnClick code below to attempt to resolve this problem but it only works if the first record in the table contains a value not in the list. When you change the value of the DBComboBox in the first record to one that is in the list, no nonconforming items will appear in the DBComboBox text. Has anyone found a solution to this?

```
procedure TForm1.DBNavigator1Click(Sender: TObject; Button: TNavigateBtn);
var
    SavePlace : TBookmark;
begin
  if (DBComboBox1.Text='') then begin
    SavePlace := TADODataSet(DBNavigator1.DataSource.DataSet).GetBookmark;
    TADODataSet(DBNavigator1.DataSource.DataSet).Requery;
    TADODataSet(DBNavigator1.DataSource.DataSet).GotoBookMark(SavePlace);
    TADODataSet(DBNavigator1.DataSource.DataSet).FreeBookMark(SavePlace);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you using the DBComboBox to set the value of a field involved in establishing the M->D connection between the datasets, and if so, which field is it setting?    If so a TDBLookUpComboBox might be a better choice.

Comment: @MartynA no the DBComboBox is used to set the value of a field that has no relationship whatsoever to any other table.

Comment: Oh, ok, I just wondered why you mentioned the M->D aspect.  As it isn't, it might be better to edit it out of your q as a distracting irrelevance, particularly in the q's title.

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce the results you describe, but what happens differs depending on the Delphi version. In D7 I get what you describe, but it Delphi Seattle I don't. Which version are you using?  Also, in D7, if I perform your steps, my test app faults (and opens the CPU windows) during the call to Application.Free.   I haven't managed to trace exactly where this happens (yet) but suspect it may be related.

Comment: @MartynA I'm using Delphi XE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have XE installed, but I have made a sample project which
reproduces your problem in D7 and Seattle.  The code is shown below and I think
you will find that if you follow the exact steps below, it shows that there is something
rather strange going on.  **Update** See the bottom of the answer for a possible work-around, which I think is preferable to the code you quote in your q.

As you'll see, except for Form1 itself, all the components are created at runtime
entirely in code.  This is to remove any doubt whether the behaviour is caused
by some obscure property setting (it isn't) and in case you wish to submit it
to EMBA as a bug report.  For a similar reason I've used a TClientDataSet so that
the app does not depend on any external data.

Steps  (please follow steps 4-7 **exactly** the first time you try them)

1. Restart the IDE and create a new project and edit the .Pas file for the main form as shown below.  The reason for restarting the IDE is that I discovered that if it has been running for a long time (two days in my case) the details of the misbehaviour 
   of the app change slightly).
2. Compile and run.
3. The app will start with the first from in the DBGrid selected.
4. Type anything (an 'X' will do) into the DBComboBox, then click the Save toolbutton
   on the DBNavigator.
5. Click the Next (>) toolbutton on the DBNavigator once only.  The DBComboBox now displays
   'Two'.
6. Click the Prior (<) toolbutton on the DBNavigator once only.  The DBComboBox is now empty.
7. Click the Prior (<) toolbutton on the DBNavigator once only.  The DBComboBox now displays
   what you typed in step 4.
8. Close the app.  Most likely the IDE debugger will catch a fault and open the CPU window.
   This fault occurs on the line

   DestroyWindow(FHandle);

in TApplication.Destroy.  I am no Windows internals expert but I think it's likely that this is because of some corruption being caused by whatever causes the blank result in step 6.  The fact that
step 7 causes the DBComboBox to correctly display what you typed makes me suspect that cause is actually
in the way the DBComboBox interacts with its FieldDataLink which connects it to the dataset.

Btw, the fact that the fault does not occur if you call DBComboBox1.Free in TForm1's FormDestroy
seems to me to confirm that the fault is related to whatever is causing your problem.

All this, and the fact that it has apparently passed unnoticed in the 25 years of Delphi, seems very strange
to me.  This demo app can show up another quirk that's been lurking in the DBGrid for a similar length  ot time.  To see
it:

9. Comment out all the references to the DBComboBox and reinstate dgMultiSelect amongst the grid options in the
   line that sets them.  Compile and run the app.
10. Click in the cell in the Name column for the first row, type something and save it.
11. Click the Next toolbutton once.  The first row does not de-select itself as it should.
    AFAICT (by displaying the DBGrid's count of Bookmarks on the form's caption) this is not
    because it has saved a bookmark on the first row.

While I've been writing this, a possible work-around has occurred to me, which I'll updated
this to include if I can get it to work.

Code

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender : TObject);
  private
    procedure SetUpDataSet;
    procedure SetUpGUI;
  protected
  public
    ClientDataSet1 : TClientDataSet;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    DBComboBox1: TDBComboBox;
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.SetUpGUI;
begin

  ClientDataset1 := TClientDataSet.Create(Self);

  DataSource1 := TDataSource.Create(Self);
  DataSource1.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

  DBGrid1 := TDBGrid.Create(Self);
  DBGrid1.Top := 8;
  DBGrid1.Left := 8;
  DBGrid1.Width := 425;
  DBGrid1.Options := [dgEditing, dgTitles, dgColumnResize, dgColLines, dgRowLines, dgTabs, dgConfirmDelete, dgCancelOnExit{, dgMultiSelect}];
  DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;
  DBGrid1.Parent := Self;

  DBNavigator1 := TDBNavigator.Create(Self);
  DBNavigator1.DataSource := DataSource1;
  DBNavigator1.Top := 144;
  DBNavigator1.Left := 16;
  DBNavigator1.Parent := Self;

  DBComboBox1 := TDBComboBox.Create(Self);
  DBComboBox1.DataField := 'Name';
  DBComboBox1.DataSource := DataSource1;
  DBComboBox1.Top := 240;
  DBComboBox1.Left := 16;
  DBComboBox1.Parent := Self;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetUpDataSet;
var
  Field : TField;
begin

  //  Create 2 fields in the CDS

  Field := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'ID';
  Field.FieldKind := fkData;
  Field.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

  Field := TStringField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'Name';
  Field.Size := 40;
  Field.FieldKind := fkData;
  Field.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetUpGUI;
  SetUpDataSet;

  //  Set up DBComboBox

  DBComboBox1.Style := csDropDown;
  DBComboBox1.Items.Add('One');
  DBComboBox1.Items.Add('Two');
  DBComboBox1.Items.Add('Three');

  //  Next, set up the CDS
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;

  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([1, '']);
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([2, 'Two']);
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([3, '']);

  ClientDataSet1.First;

end;
```

**Possible work-around** Add the following method to Form1:

```
procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  S : String;
begin
  S := DataSet.FieldByName('Name').AsString;
  if S <> DbComboBox1.Text then
    DbComboBox1.Text := S;
  Caption := IntToStr(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count);

end;
```

Then, in the `SetUpGUI` method, add the following immediately after the line where ClientDataSet1 is created:

```
ClientDataset1.AfterScroll := ClientDataSet1AfterScroll;
```

I have not tested this thoroughly, but it seems to work in the test conditions of the steps I've described above.

Comment: Thanks, MartynA. I applied your solution of manually setting the Text and it seems to have fixed the problem. In my case the value would be blank but if the user entered any other TDBEdit attached to the same datasource, the value would appear. I'm using 10.3 Rio.